# How to register UDP ports in Linux Kernel and creating hook for this port range

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel

I am newbie to the Linux Kernel. I am writing kernel module, this module handles multiple UDP voice streams. For this module, I want to register multiple UDP ports of different voice streams in Kernel, so that other UDP traffic wont be able to use these UDP ports. As per my understanding creating a socket and binding is one way.

I also want to create a hook function for these UDP voice ports, so that whenever the voice packets received it will call my hook function.

I have few questions:

- Is there any better way to register multiple UDP ports in Linux Kernel, other than creating socket and binding it?
- How to create a hook function, and call it for these registered multiple UDP voice Ports?

Comment: I have to ask - why are you doing this in the kernel?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: If you had not asked, I would have. Looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: I apologies for misunderstanding. I am writing Linux Module running in Kernel space. In Kernel, i only want to create hook for these UDP Voice packets. So that whenever the Voice Packets comes with those UDP ports, it will send it to my Module.

Comment: And my question was why does it have to be a kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is this: If you have to ask, then you shouldn't do it.

Here's the longer version:

TCP/IP programming is one of those areas where the API is geared toward user space using it. The result is that there is no easy way to create TCP/IP (which includes UDP) sockets from the kernel.

Even if you managed it, you'd find the APIs you have are not suited. The code will try to manipulate user space memory, user space notification etc. when you use it.

An experienced enough kernel developer can, probably, pull it off. Someone who has to go to Stack Overflow to even get started, however, is probably not experienced enough.

Which brings us back to the original question: why do you want to write such code in the kernel anyways? Voice over IP is a complicated protocol. Debugging code in the kernel is considerably harder than debugging user space code, not to mention error recovery when things go wrong.

If you are writing code that absolutely has to have high performance and low latency, I suggest you have a look at basing your solution on pure user space (i.e. - no kernel at all).

Such a solution is [DPDK](http://dpdk.org/). It allows you to receive the network packets directly into user space buffers. Unfortunately, this is not a solution designed for beginners either. Since there is no kernel involved, the interface must be exclusively used for DPDK. This also means you have to write your own UDP stack to support it.

DPDK is not a simple tool to use, but if you must have the absolute highest bandwidth with the absolute lowest latency, it is the best solution around. Probably better than writing the entire VoIP stack in kernel. If that is not what you need, then just use normal sockets programming tools.